# Parse multiple values of a UAML field to a list and iterate over it in GOLANG

Tags: email, go, yaml, smtplib

I have the following yaml file with me:

```
nodes: ["1.1.1.1","127.0.0.1","2.2.2.2"]
emailto: ["sample@sample.com","sample@sample.com"]
```

I want to open the YAML file,  iterate over the IPs one by one and do some certain action. If there is an error, then it should automatically take the next ip and perform the same function. I am having trouble as to how to save the IPs to a list or how to iterate in GOLANG.

Also, I have to send an email based to the e-mail IDs present in the YAML file. Which package in GO is used for that and how to do it like SMTPLIB in Python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why isn't your attempted solution working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are three parts to your question:

#### 1. See [`gopkg.in/yaml.v2`](https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2) for YAML parsing

```
import (
  // ...
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Doc struct {
  Nodes  []string `yaml:"nodes"`
  Emails []string `yaml:"emailto"`
}

// Parse the YAML document.
doc := Doc{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlbytes, &doc)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("FATAL: could not parse YAML file: %s", err)
}
```

#### 2. Example of iterating using `range`, calling a function, and handling errors

```
// Iterate over each node and do something, handling errors as needed.
for _, node := range doc.Nodes {
  err := DoSomethingWithNode(node)
  if err != nil {
    log.Printf("ERROR: failed to handle node %q: %s", node, err)
  } else {
    log.Printf("OK: successfully handled node %q.", node)
  }
}
```

#### 3. See the builtin [`net/smtp` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/) for sending email

See the [package example](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#example_) for a complete illustration.